# Displayed duplicate records while i have used distinct in sql

Tags: sql, distinct

I have written a query to find the second highest salary. I am using the distinct keyword but it retrieved duplicate records. How do you retrieve distinct records?

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
     Employees e 
WHERE 
     (1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.Salary))
            FROM 
                 Employees p
            WHERE 
                 p.Salary > e.Salary)
```

[image]

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: You posted an image, if this is the current result it's correct (there are 2 rows with the same salary)

Comment: What is WHERE [1]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I think you need to use a ranking function

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM Employees e WHERE (1) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.Salary))FROM Employees p WHERE p.Salary > e.Salary)
```

Comment: You cannot have DISTINCT alone in select query without specifying column names

Comment: we use distinct directly for removing the duplicate value so trying to use distinct in place of *

Comment: No you cant do that without an identifier for it

Comment: but i solved many question on hackerrank for removing duplicate value with the help of distinct keyword